# Use of "that of" (e.g. "that of in")

Tags: comparisons

Sentence in question:

> The total amount of donation in 2010 has surpassed **that of in 1990**.

Can you use "that of" as a tool to compare the difference in volume of a same thing in different years?

Comment: Sure,  But choose only one of *of* and *in*.

Comment: I find this ungrammatical, though perfectly comprehensible. Others may disagree.

Comment: You should parallel -- use either "in" or "of" both places.  And only use one.

Comment: Somehow it is clumsy. I would avoid "of in"  and say "surpassed that of the year 1990.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but the use of "that of" is not limited to be used only for a comparison of something in different years or even time.
Examples:

> Old English grammar is more complicated than that of Modern English.
>
> As a teacher, his salary is even less than that of a driver.

Comment: But "that of in" is not right.